# Refer auxiliary xsd file from main xsd file using schemaLocation

Tags: xml, xsd

I am developing an app where i need to interpret the response xml. 
I am using xsd file for it.

I have subscription.xsd (listed below) which refers s.xsd file. Both these files are under the same folder in the app (e.g. Resources).

But the issue is, if try to use the simple path e.g. schemaLocation="s.xsd" i get this error: Failed to read included schema document 's.xsd'. I tried few combinations but nothing could solve the problem.

Is there a way i can make this reference generic so that it will work when i deploy it on linux platform.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"  targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:s="http://www.somename.com/subscription">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.somename.com/subs/subscription" schemaLocation="file:/C:/MyApp/schma_defs/s.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="feed">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="atom:id"/>
          <xs:element ref="atom:title"/>
          <xs:element ref="atom:author"/>
        </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ways to make `schemaLocation` consistent across platforms:**

- Use the same directory as the referencing XSD:

  - `schemaLocation="s.xsd"`
- Use a directory relative to the referencing XSD:

  - `schemaLocation="../xsds/s.xsd"`
- Use a mutually accessible, common network location at which you can place the XSD:

  - `schemaLocation="http://www.somename.com/subs/subscription/s.xsd"`